# Select rows em um array PostgreSQL

Tags: array, python, postgresql, query

Estou usando o banco de dados PostgreSQL e Python para consulta-lo, tenho a seguinte modelagem:

[image: tabelas]

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta que me retorne todos os `OrderItems` de uma `Order` em um `array`, para isso fiz o seguinte código:

```
select ARRAY(
    SELECT '(' || translate(string_to_array(x.*::"text", ',')::text, '{()}', '') || ')' 
    from "OrderItem" x
)::"OrderItem"[] AS "_AAA";
```

O que me retorna o seguinte resultado:

```
"{"(16,1,ProductName1,M,45.00,1,6)","(17,6,ProductName2,M,45.00,1,6)"}"
```

No Python estou usando `psycopg2` para conversar com o banco, e sendo assim ele me retorna uma string, assim como no resultado acima, não conseguindo iterar por ela para pegar as tuplas com os valores.

Alguém tem idéia de como posso fazer essa query para retornar um array de OrderItem ?

Comment: Você pode compartilhar o select que você escreveu com o python? você pode tentar usar um dict-like cursor: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#dictionary-like-cursor

Comment: O select no python foi um teste, então foi "SELECT * FROM NomeDaView WHERE "OrderId"=10;". Estou usando dict cursor, e me retorna um dicionário onde a key é "OrderItems" e o value é o resultado que coloquei ali no post, então ele nao faz esse parse sozinho.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que você quer agregar as linhas da tabela `orderItem`

```
select array_agg(orderItem) as "_AAA"
from orderItem
where orderId = 10
```

Isto deverá retornar uma lista de tuplas.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html